# Double ssh to worker host through master and run file check

Tags: bash, ssh

From a local server, I'm trying to check for file distribution across an array. The check requires that I ssh into the master server then into each worker to check for files. I'm having trouble getting the double ssh hop to work.

From the shell I can get it to work fine:

```
master=master_server.com
worker=worker_server.com
filename=/path/file.config

ssh -q $master "ssh -q $worker \"[ -e $filename ]\" && echo $filename found on $worker"
```

But when I create an .sh script, this same call doesn't work. Instead, the script ssh's into the first worker in the array and leaves me at the command line without having executed the file check. Using `exit`, I can manually log off the worker and the script resumes, but for each subsequent worker I get:

```
worker2.com: Command not found.
worker3.com: Command not found.
...
```

I've tried different combinations of single and double quotes. I've also tried including the -t flag.

How can I ssh across two servers and test for a file?

Comment: Consider removing the quiet flag (-q), and possibly increasing the logging (-v or -vv). Might be a problem with the ssh sequence.

Comment: Show the script?